# SQL - Left outer join with 2 tables and derived tables

Tags: mysql

My scenario is as follows:

```
Table Persons  
- id (primary key)  
- name  

Table Logs  
- id (primary key)  
- person_id (foreign key)  
- datetime  
- status
```

Now I want to create a SQL query in order to retrieve:

- All names from Persons without a relation with the table Logs
- and with a relation with the table Logs that are linked with the field id and person_id.
- Only the latest records by person from the table Logs (ie the latest log id)

This query retrieves only names with a matched relation:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, DATE_FORMAT(l.datetime,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS datetime, l.status 
        FROM Persons p LEFT OUTER JOIN Logs l 
        ON p.id = l.person_id
        WHERE l.id IN (SELECT id from Logs T1 
            INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS Max_id FROM Logs 
            GROUP BY person_id
            ) T2
            ON T1.id = T2.Max_id)
        ORDER BY l.status, p.name";
```

How do I get the names without a relation with the table Logs as well?

Comment: A cross join perhaps?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so (you haven't), provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so (again, you haven't), provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT p.name 
FROM Persons p 
LEFT JOIN Logs l ON p.id = l.person_id
WHERE l.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just need to add the WHERE clause l.id IS NULL to my query. The following query gives the desired result:
  SELECT p.id, p.name, DATE_FORMAT(l.datetime,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS datetime, l.status 
        FROM Persons p LEFT OUTER JOIN Logs l 
        ON p.id = l.person_id
        WHERE l.id IN (SELECT id from Logs T1 
            INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS Max_id FROM Logs 
            GROUP BY person_id
            ) T2
            ON T1.id = T2.Max_id)
          OR l.id IS NULL
        ORDER BY l.status, p.name";